# "No such file or directory" trying to write NTFS

Tags: mount, lubuntu, ntfs-3g

I have booted from an LUbuntu 18.04 Live USB.  I am trying to access the files on my hard drive (Windows 10, NTFS).  By default they are mounted read only, so I remounted it read-write with no errors.  (This is with the ntfs-3g driver in user space.)  But when I try to write to files on the drive, I always get this error:

"No such file or directory"

For instance, if I chdir to my home directory on the drive and run "echo > tmp.txt" I get the error:

"bash: tmp.txt: No such file or directory"

If I try to make a copy of a file in the File Manager, I get this error:

file1.txt: Error opening file “/media/lubuntu/Windows8_OS/Users/michael/Downloads/file1.txt”: No such file or directory

I tried running ntfs-fix, but it found no issues.

Why can't I write to my drive?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to remount the read-only partition, unmount the partition and mount it in a separate step.  First the unmount (replace the directory as needed with wherever your Windows drive is mounted):

```
sudo umount /media/lubuntu/Windows8_OS
```

Next run `ntfsfix` (`sudo apt install ntfs-3g` if the command is not found) just in case the drive wasn't unmounted properly.  This could happen, for instance, if you properly shut down but then aborted a Windows start due to the BIOS running away before you could select your USB media to boot from.

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4
```

The above assumes the NTFS file system is at `/dev/sda4`. Replace as needed with your device (`lsblk` may be helpful to determine where it is).

Now mount it:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

Don't forget to unmount it when you are done:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```