# Unable to create or edit files in existing directory. Error: "No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, directory

I'm pretty new to using the command line. I recently installed Ubuntu and have been playing around with some simple commands. I have found that there are some directories in which I cannot create a new file or edit an existing. This only appears to be happening in directories under the `user` directory, such as `Desktop`, `Documents`...

E.g. this works fine:

```
iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane$ touch test.txt
```

However these do not:

```
iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': No such file or directory

iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Documents$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': No such file or directory
```

Attempting to edit and save changes in an existing file in these directories produces the following:

`[ Error writing test_edit.txt: Permission denied ]`

### Troubleshooting

I've tried the following, without success:

1. Permissions don't seem to be an issue

```
iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ stat /mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop
  File: /mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop
  Size: 512             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 512    directory
Device: ch/12d  Inode: 54606145481977805  Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/iboopedu)   Gid: ( 1000/iboopedu)
Access: 2019-04-25 11:55:52.524860400 +1000
Modify: 2019-04-25 11:40:54.971595700 +1000
Change: 2019-04-25 11:40:54.971595700 +1000
```

2. Running as admin (both running Ubuntu as administrator and also the command as admin)

```
iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ sudo touch test.txt
[sudo] password for iboopedu:
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': No such file or directory
```

3. Have been receiving some advice from my Slack community and tried the following

```
iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ touch ./test.txt
touch: cannot touch './test.txt': No such file or directory

iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ touch /mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop/test.txt
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop/test.txt': No such file or directory

iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ test -d ./ && echo "Directory exists"
Directory exists

iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ test -d /mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop && echo "Directory exists"
Directory exists

iboopedu@CODE1026:/mnt/c/Users/shane/Desktop$ > test.txt
-bash: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

So that's where we are! Hoping someone can help please.
TIA

Comment: Is this NTFS? If yes, then you might take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138724/no-such-file-or-directory-message-when-deleting-a-file-that-exists-on-ntfs) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051681/no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-write-ntfs).

Comment: Thanks @Nykakin I ran `chkdsk` on c: in read-only to see what errors it would bring back before removing, however, none were found. ```Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.```

Comment: I still suspect this is a NTFS problem. I suggest googling keywords `NFTS` and `Linux` together your error message, `No such file or directory` to further investigate the problem. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the subject myself.

Comment: Thanks @Nykakin the search continues...